# How can I make an IDE aware of symbol information from JavaScript CDNs?

Tags: javascript, cdn, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm using neovim with the included LSP support, but I have the same issue in VS Code. I'm writing browser-side javascript using a library from a CDN, and of course my language server doesn't have diagnostic/symbolic information from the CDN. I'd love to be able to tab-complete functions defined in the library, or access signature help.

How can I do this?

Edit: I want to add that I'm 100% okay with installing a local copy of the library, a comment below pointed out that loading remote definitions isn't supported in VS Code. I'm not sure how to reference a local library from a js file that runs in the browser.

Comment: For VSCode: [How to get external library intellisense to work in vscode for javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56405311/215552). See also [the VS Code documentation itself](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense-is-not-working-for-external-libraries). I don't know anything about neovim.

Comment: That's definitely very helpful and I'll dig through that to see if I can figure out how to apply it to neovim.

I'm not an expert and I'm currently exploring lsp on neovim. I do believe that I'm using the same language server for autocompletion that vscode uses.